# function that worked in bash does not work in zsh

Tags: zsh

I used a bash script multiple times per day on my 2015 MBP to detect and find open ports.

```
rogue() {
  local PORTS="1234 3000 4200 4567 5000 5432 6379 7777 7778 8000 8888 27017 9000 8080 8081"
  local MESSAGE="> Checking for processes on ports"
  local COMMAND="lsof"

  for PORT in $PORTS; do
    MESSAGE="${MESSAGE} ${PORT},"
    COMMAND="${COMMAND} -i TCP:${PORT}"
  done

  echo "${MESSAGE%?}..."
  local OUTPUT="$(${COMMAND})"

  if [ -z '$OUTPUT' ]; then
    echo "> Nothing running!"
  else
    echo "> Processes found:"
    printf "\n$OUTPUT\n\n"
    echo "> Use the 'kill' command with the 'PID' of any process you want to quit."
    echo "> Use 'kill -9 PID' to kill all duplicate processes"
    echo
  fi
}`
```

I upgraded to a M1 MBP and the script doesn't work.

```
> Checking for processes on ports 1234 3000 4200 4567 5000 5432 6379 7777 7778 8000 8888 27017 9000 8080 8081...
rogue:11: command not found: lsof -i TCP:1234 3000 4200 4567 5000 5432 6379 7777 7778 8000 8888 27017 9000 8080 8081
> Processes found:



> Use the 'kill' command with the 'PID' of any process you want to quit.
> Use 'kill -9 PID' to kill all duplicate processes
```

It looks like the `for in` loop isn't doing what I expected. I did try a few other things (see below) and now just `bash`ing (or cra`zsh`ing) my head against the wall.

I tried this but my zsh is trash.

```
rogue() {
  ports=("1234" "3000" "4200" "4567" "5000" "5432" "6379" "7777" "7778" "8000" "8888" "27017" "9000" "8080" "8081")
  message="> Checking for processes on ports"
  command="lsof"

  for port in "{$ports[@]}"; do
    message="$message $port"
    command="$command -i TCP:$port"
  done

  echo "$message ..."
  output="$command"

  if [ -z "$output" ]; then
    echo "> Nothing running!"
  else
    echo "> Processes found:"
    printf "\n$output\n\n"
    echo "> Use the 'kill' command with the 'PID' of any process you want to quit."
    echo "> Use 'kill -9 PID' to kill all duplicate processes"
    echo
  fi
}
```

output:

`lsof -i TCP:{1234 -i TCP:3000 -i TCP:4200 -i TCP:4567 -i TCP:5000 -i TCP:5432 -i TCP:6379 -i TCP:7777 -i TCP:7778 -i TCP:8000 -i TCP:8888 -i TCP:27017 -i TCP:9000 -i TCP:8080 -i TCP:8081}`

Any ideas/suggestions/answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aside from the error which I pointed out in my answer, the loop in your function is pointless. In each iteration you add another piece of `-i TCP:$port` to your `command`, and in the end, the string `command` will contain **all** ports. Run your script with `set -x` to observe this.

Comment: In the first variant posted, `[ -z '$OUTPUT' ]` will always be false (for zsh and bash). In the second variant you posted, you never execute the command stored in `command`, and `output` is simply a copy of `command`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, why do you expect that a program written for one language would work the same for a different language? While bash and zsh indeed have so many similarities that you can, with some care, create code which works identical on both of them, you have to anticipate this when you start writing that code.

In your case,

```
local OUTPUT="$(${COMMAND})"
```

for instance causes you trouble. In bash, parameter expansion occurs before wordsplitting. Assume for brevity that `command` would contain the string `lsof -i TCP:8081` (which is **not** exactly the value you get from your code). In this case you effectively execute in bash the command `lsof` with the parameters `-i` and `TCP:8081`. In zsh howeve, wordsplitting is done before parameter expansion, and you execute a command with the *name* `lsof -i TCP:8081`.

In zsh you could write

```
 local OUTPUT=$(${(z)COMMAND})
```

instead. The `(z)` causes wordsplitting before interpolation.

While this would work with such simple commands as in your case, this approach would fail (in bash and in zsh), if the command contained arguments which in turn have white spaces. In general, when you want to store a complete command into a variable, you are better off using an array instead of a string. For instance,

```
command=(lsof -i TCP:$port)
OUTPUT=$(${command})
```

would work in zsh. In bash you would have written

```
OUTPUT=$("${command[@]}")
```